# Python automation, get focus to Chrome browser, get URL

Tags: python, windows, url, automation

I'm a python dummy, but have been successful in automating many of my windows 10 tasks.  I'm stumped on how to get one piece of information for my current automation script.  Let me explain:
I am using a web-based CRM solution that contains customer information.  I do a select all (cntl-a) then use pyperclip to copy all of the customer information from the CRM system to the clipboard, and then I look for specific fields within the clipboard and format that information into a new record format to then be pasted into another web application via pyperclip. All that works great.  But I need to include the URL for the specific CRM customer entry.  How do I get the URL address from my Python script for the current tab on my Chrome browser? Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get Chrome tab URL in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52675506/get-chrome-tab-url-in-python)