# Get Active Chrome URL in Python

Tags: python, google-chrome, ui-automation, win32gui

I was trying to use uiautomation's python wrapper to get the active url of a chrome window. However, this script was only getting certain websites (such as youtube or google) and not others (stackoverflow, reddit, github etc.)

```
import win32gui as win
import time
import uiautomation as auto

while True:
    window = win.GetForegroundWindow()
    win_name = win.GetWindowText(window)
    if "Google Chrome" in win_name:
        chromeControl = auto.ControlFromHandle(window)
        edit = chromeControl.EditControl()
        print('https://' + edit.GetValuePattern().Value)
```

I have tried almost every post regarding this matter to no avail. Apparently chrome has changed their window class names etc. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your program as whole meant to do? There might be another library which is better suited to the task.

Comment: I want to get the active application, but if the application is chrome: get the url or base website.

Comment: Ah, never mind then.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get Chrome tab URL in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52675506/get-chrome-tab-url-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way to do it:

```
import uiautomation as auto


control = auto.GetFocusedControl()
controlList = []
while control:
    controlList.insert(0, control)
    control = control.GetParentControl()
    
control = controlList[0 if len(controlList) == 1 else 1]
    
address_control = auto.FindControl(control, lambda c, d: 
                                            isinstance(c, auto.EditControl))

print('Current URL:')
print(address_control.GetValuePattern().Value)
```

you can also then set some new value for the OmniBox:

```
address_control.GetValuePattern().SetValue('http://some_url')
```